# Sending alert upon HTML update using AutoIT

Tags: html, ui-automation, autoit

This might be a long shot, but I have a situation at work in which some automation will be useful. At my work, we use an activity log system that logs events across our workspace. Every few seconds, we get a new event in the activity log, so it's always updating. Is it possible to use AutoIT to constantly read that activity log and create a pop-up notification when a certain message is presented?

*(i.e. Alarm received, send notification and sound displaying the alarm, the individual involved, and the location of the alarm)*

Any help would be appreciated, even just a slight push in the general direction

--UPDATE--
[image: HTML of the webpage]

The picture above shows the HTML of the website I use at work. The section labeled <table id="activityLog5" contains a constantly updating list of events as events happen throughout the day. If this makes it easier, there you all go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we talked about alternates of AutoIT, here would be the Script Idea for a Grease Monkey Script:

```js
// Basicly your GreaseMonkey Script:

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var tableToMonitor = document.getElementById('activityLog5');
    var lastTimeChecked = tableToMonitor.rows.length;
    var intervalHandle = setInterval(function () {
        if (lastTimeChecked === tableToMonitor.rows.length) {
            return;
        }
        lastTimeChecked = tableToMonitor.rows.length;
            // Play your Sound
            // do what ever you want
            // finally make an alert
            setTimeout(function() {
                alert('NEW EVENT');
            }, 1);
    }, 1000); // check every second
});

// ---- Debug Code - not part of your script anymore
var next_id = 2;
function addLog() {
    var newEventRow = document.getElementById('activityLog5').insertRow(-1);
    newEventRow.id = next_id.toString();
    var newEventBox = newEventRow.insertCell(0);
    newEventBox.appendChild(document.createTextNode('New Event'));
    next_id = next_id + 1;
}
```

```html
    <input type="button" value="Create a new Event" onclick="addLog()"/>
    <table id="activityLog5">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="1"><td>Log Entry</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```